# Selenium tests fail when more instances are run

Tags: php, selenium, jenkins

I am running Selenium Docker container with Firefox and VNC controlled by Jenkins server with PHPUnit.

However when I try to run multiple Jenkins jobs at one time, all the Selenium tests fail. They do not look "suspicious" when looked at by VNC, but they fail.

Does anybody know what might be wrong ?
In case you need more info, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: It can be for a number of reasons. I'll put my money on the way you instatiate your remote webdriver can you share those lines please?

Comment: @XwrisStoixeia       $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://192.168.127.90:44444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities::firefox());

Comment: Okay, so it looks like your webDriver isn't static this is what I wanted to check. Is your failure related to not being able to locate an element? If yes, then it might be down to several of your scripts sharing the same findElement information causing each other to fail. Sorry, I couldn't be more helpful, but the question is rather vague. Please also include error message along with the stack trace if possible please.

Comment: @XwrisStoixeia well just to be sure I updated everything on the way from Jenkins to Selenium and it works now. Thanks for your comments

Comment: Glad if I was of some help Jesse. Don't trust Walter man, he will get you killed! :)